# IntegrityError at /admin/seo/mymetadatamodelinstance/add/

Tags: python, django, seo

I am developing a site using django framework. For this, i have implemented django-SEO packages and as usual, four models are created in the admin. But when i try to save data in the "Model Instance" table, it gives below mentioned error. I don't have any idea about how to accomplish the task. Any help is much appreciated.

(1048, "Column '_content_type_id' cannot be null")

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check this. http://django-seo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/tutorial.html

Comment: @m170897017 I have implemented the same in my project but unfortunately seo section is not showing in the admin side.